# Django Advanced DB Query

Tags: django, oracle, django-models, django-views

I'm running a very complicated query against oracle to return some data. I'm running it manually because django can't natively do what I am doing from what I have read.
I run the query but django doesn't get any values in return. I recently switched from my dev database to my production to run the query because it has live data and the required
data doesn't exist in dev yet because its a new feature.

The query executes but doesn't return anything. However there is another very similarly query that I am running that is returning data. Also if I output the exact statement
django is using to make the query against oracle for the data that is not returning and then if i goto terminal and execute the query against the sql server manually it will return the data.
I also output the fetchall to the page as a debuging tool and the working query has all the info but the none working one outputs blank list.

At first I thought it was the query but i have proven the query django is using works but django gets no data. The only logical answer is django is trying to use the dev database or the models table something is off.
However I ran syncdb and sql and no errors came up... If I run the query against dev it doesnt return data, but does against production.

Here is the query I am running.

```
if 'customer_licenses_all' in request.POST:
 return_query_type = 'customer_licenses_all'
 cursor.execute("alter session set time_zone='UTC'")
 selected_customer_id = int(selected_customer['selected_customer'])       
 rundate = selected_customer['compute_date']
 date2 = datetime.strptime(rundate, "%d-%b-%Y")
 date_list = ()
 date_list = (date2.day, date2.month, date2.year)
 last_date =  get_last_day(date_list)
 last_date = last_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

 sql = (('''select customer_name, count(*) license_count, sum(cpu_ghz_hours) CPU_Core_Hours, sum(ram_gb_hours) RAM_GB_Hours, licensing_authority, product 
            from customers a, vm_groups b, vms c, vm_license_histories d, licenses e, vm_compute_usage_histories f, license_authorities g 
            where a.customer_id = b.customer_id 
            and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id 
            and c.vm_id = d.vm_id 
            and d.license_id = e.license_id 
            and f.vm_id = c.vm_id 
            and e.license_authority_id = g.license_authority_id 
            and trunc(f.datetime) = to_date(%s,'DD-MON-YYYY') 
            and inactive = 'N' 
            and (deassignment_date is null or trunc(deassignment_date) between to_date(%s,'DD-MON-YYYY') and last_day(to_date(%s,'DD-MON-YYYY'))) 
            and cpu_ghz_hours > 0 
            and g.license_authority_id not in (28,27,31) 
            group by customer_name, licensing_authority, product order by 1,5,6''')% ("'"+rundate+"'","'"+ rundate+"'" ,"'"+last_date+"'"))
 cursor.execute(sql)
 return_query = cursor.fetchall()    
 context = Context({'customers': customers,
                       'return_query': return_query,
                       'return_query_type':return_query_type, 
                       'rundate':rundate,
                       'last_date':last_date, 
                       'sql':sql, 
                       })
```

the django output

> select customer_name, count(*) license_count, sum(cpu_ghz_hours)
>   CPU_Core_Hours, sum(ram_gb_hours) RAM_GB_Hours, licensing_authority,
>   product from customers a, vm_groups b, vms c, vm_license_histories d,
>   licenses e, vm_compute_usage_histories f, license_authorities g where
>   a.customer_id = b.customer_id and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id and
>   c.vm_id = d.vm_id and d.license_id = e.license_id and f.vm_id =
>   c.vm_id and e.license_authority_id = g.license_authority_id and
>   trunc(f.datetime) = to_date('01-Jun-2014','DD-MON-YYYY') and inactive
>   = 'N' and (deassignment_date is null or trunc(deassignment_date) between to_date('01-Jun-2014','DD-MON-YYYY') and
>   last_day(to_date('30-Jun-2014','DD-MON-YYYY'))) and cpu_ghz_hours > 0
>   and g.license_authority_id not in (28,27,31) group by customer_name,
>   licensing_authority, product order by 1,5,6
>
> []

Comment: So just like you said, are you sure you're connected to the production DB? Check your settings.py file.


Also I'd try a simple 'select *' query to see if it's connected properly... Because if the query works against the DB it should work when you execute it through django

Comment: yea i set the settings file and the username and password i logged in with changed to the one i have to use when using the production database.

Comment: So I tracked down an issue, whenever I change my database from development to production which have the same exact schema 
it still uses the data from development although my settings.py file is set to the production database and it even swtiches the user I have
to log in with to the one associated with production but all of the data is development. 

I have tried running sync db and sql. Nothing seems to work I know this is a django ism but not sure how to fix it .